why siginfo_t::si_addr is a wrong address which the segfault at?

I used sigaction to register signal_handler() to handle SIGSEGV, but in param siginfo_t *siginfo->si_addr, it not record the right segfault address which it occurs. The act address is 0x20020208c, but the  siginfo->si_addr value is 0x116. why? and I found in different machine, the value changed, it is 0x385 in other machine.

I don;t think there is enough information to help you,

Please don’t post images of text, for various reasons; see: PSA: Please don’t post images of text.  Instead, copy the text and paste it here as a code block.  (E.g., use “code fences” — see Markdown Editing Help and click on “show more”.)

Can you post the relevant code segment. It'll be very hard for us to guess at what might be wrong without having something to reference.
